# Can't access array element after calling helper (Handlebars)

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, helper

I've registered this helper on my app file:

```
hbs.registerHelper('if_greater', (a, b, opts) => {
    if (a >= b) return opts.fn(this);
    return opts.inverse(this);
});
```

Then, on my hbs file:

```
{{#if_greater 20 occurrences}}
     <tr class="danger">
         <td>{{this.date}}</td>
         <td>{{this.serial}}</td>
         <td>{{this.operator}}</td>
         <td>{{this.vehicle}}</td>
         <td>{{this.stop}}</td>
         <td>{{this.line}}</td>
         <td>{{this.zone}}</td>
         <td>{{this.occurrences}}</td>
         <td>{{this.encrypted}}</td>
     </tr>
{{/if_greater}}
```

However, `this.date` doesn't output anything, neither does calling `date`. I can output it if I don't call my helper. What's wrong in the helper?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are using an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) rather than a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) in your `hbs.registerHelper` call. It's important to note that arrow function expressions are *not* simply a neat new way for writing function expressions; they behave *differently*.

The relevant difference in this case is that [arrow function expressions *do not* have their own `this` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this). Instead, they get the `this` of their enclosing execution context.

When you define a Handlebars helper with an old-fashioned function expression, like `hbs.registerHelper('if_greater', function (a, b, opts) { /*...*/ });`, Handlebars takes care of ensuring that the `this` within the executed helper is the current context in your template. From the docs:

> Handlebars always invokes helpers with the current context as `this`, so you can invoke the block with `this` to evaluate the block in the current context.

However, when you use an arrow function expression, the `this` comes from the *lexical scope* in which the function is defined. `this` can be a lot of things, but it *cannot* be the template context that you want.

For a nice summary of arrow functions vs function expressions, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/3397771

For confirmation that your helper works as expected when written as a non-arrow function expression, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/py7ghrbz/).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone encounters the same problem, I found a workaround (and left the helper as it is).

```
{{#each payload as |p|}} {{#if_greater 20 occurrences}}
  <tr class="danger">
    <td>{{p.date}}</td>
    <td>{{p.serial}}</td>
    <td>{{p.operator}}</td>
    <td>{{p.vehicle}}</td>
    <td>{{p.stop}}</td>
    <td>{{p.line}}</td>
    <td>{{p.zone}}</td>
    <td>{{p.occurrences}}</td>
    <td>{{p.encrypted}}</td>
  </tr>
```