# Express Handlebars Sections don't do anything

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am currently trying to implement sections into my website using express handlebars. My code looks like this:

index.js

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const expressHandlebars = require("express-handlebars");

const app = express();
app.engine("handlebars", expressHandlebars({
    defaultLayout: "main",
    helpers: {
        section: (name, options) => {
            if (!this._sections) {
                this._sections = {};
            }
            this._sections[name] = options.fn(this);
            return null;
        }
    }
 }));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("home", { title: "Home" });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

views/layouts/main.handlebars

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{{{ title }}}</title>

        {{{_sections.head}}}
    </head>
    <body>

        {{{ body }}}

    </body>
</html>
```

views/home.handlebars

```
{{#section "head"}}
<style>
    h1 {
        color: "red";
    }
</style>
{{/section}}

<h1>test</h1>
```

### Expected Result:

It correctly displays the h1 tag with the text "test". However, the heading should be red due to the `{{#section "head"}}`, but it is black.

I have installed express and expressHandlebars correctly.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer above doesn't actually address your issue.

The real problem is: **Don't use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) when defining a Handlebars Helper.**

Because of that, `this` within the helper isn't set correctly so [rendering it our via `options.fn(this)`](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#basic-blocks) doesn't work.

So the *real* fix should be:

```js
app.engine(
    'handlebars',
    expressHandlebars({
        defaultLayout: 'main',
        helpers: {
            //  Importantly, define the helper as a regular `function`, _not_ an arrow-function.
            section(name, options) {
                if (!this._sections) {
                    this._sections = {};
                }
                this._sections[name] = options.fn(this);
                return null;
            },
        },
    })
);
```

See the bellow SO post for more information on this:

- [Can't access array element after calling helper (Handlebars)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49960278/cant-access-array-element-after-calling-helper-handlebars/49992169#49992169)

> Also, you have a typo on your CSS:
>
> ```
> h1 { color: "red" }
> ```
>
> Is not correct; The [color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value) datatype doesn't include quotes. So the correct CSS should be
>
> ```
> h1 { color: red }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It works if you declare style in head of your source html.

*views/home.handlebars* should read:

```
<head>
    <style>
        h1 {
            color: red;
            border: solid 1px green;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<h1>test</h1>
```